# RHEL based distros and FHS (and postgres)

Tags: postgresql, fhs, standard

Under CentOS, i see postgres config files are located in '/var/lib/...'  (instead of '/etc'). In FHS specifications, under '/var/lib' (chapter 5, section 8.1) it is specified:

> This hierarchy holds state information pertaining to an application or the system. State information is data that programs modify while they run, and that pertains to one specific host. **Users must never need to modify files in /var/lib to configure a package's operation ...**

Do RHEL based distros follow FHS? If yes, are there any particular reasons why postgres config files are located there ('/var/lib/...')?